# Must be paid before the 8th May?

Tags: grammar

Does that mean I can pay on the 8th May, or before 23:59 7th May?

Comment: Literally, it means you're late if you pay on May 8. Whether that's what was intended depends on context we don't have.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of a lease or contract.

Comment: It seems it should be _before May 8th_ or _before the 8th of May_.  Does the construct above appear like usual use in non-AmE speaking areas?  I'm aware, we reference our dates differently in other uses.  And, it does imply that making the payment on May 8th would be late.

Comment: Just pay on May 6th. Why wonder whether *a minute* will make a difference if you can just pay in good time, or indeed *right now*? Nowhere does it say the payment has to be last-minute, so that's a trouble you yourself introduce.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking - that is, making a literal interpretation - "before 8th May" means "on May 8, you must already have paid". However, this is quite an ambiguous case: you might want to contact the person to be paid to ensure that your interpretation is correct. It is also a good idea to read any text that might apply to the payment, e.g. a contract, Terms of Service, smallprint, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning is clear, and payment must be made by 7 May at the latest. However in a business context, it would usually be taken to mean "by the close of business on 8 May", ie by the end of that day.

Of course in the pedantic world of corporate lawyers, there could be arguments about what time of day ought to be construed as the close of business (taking into account the norms for the relevant industry, the time zones involved, etc), whether the bank account needs to have been credited with good value (ie cleared funds), and other such tedious details.

If more precision is required then the original source must be amended to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

To certain ears, saying "must be paid before the 8th" can indeed sound equivocal, and sort of "mind-boggling" somehow, as long as one can interpret it as meaning "anytime before the 8th," i.e. payments will be overdue on the 8th. Or, as meaning "anytime not after the 8th," hence payment still will be accepted on the 8th.

On the other hand, "before" followed with a clause conveys a meaning that is, generally, unquestionably clear, e.g. delinquent accounts must be paid in full **before a student registers** for additional courses.

For deadline situations implying a target date like in your example, a safer option would be to use the preposition ["by"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by) or the idiomatic "no later than," to keep any risks of misunderstanding at bay. E. g. delinquent accounts must be paid in full **by/no later than** the 8th.

That being said, if I was asked to pay something before the 8th, chances are I would understand it as meaning "anytime before that date."